# return longest word from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to define a function called "len_score" that returns the length of a word. Call the "best" function with the len_score function as a parameter.

Output I want to be:
print(best(len_score, names), "has the longest name.")

McJagger has the longest name.

My code is:

```
def len_score(name):
    lst=[len(x) for x in name]
    return lst
def best(lst1,lst2):
    final=zip(lst1,lst2)
    return max final

names = ["Ben", "April", "Zaber", "Alexis", "McJagger", "J.J.", "Madonna"]

print(best(len_score, names) == 'McJagger')
```

But I got error and not sure how to set condition on the list.

Comment: If you want to find the longest word in a list you can just use `max(names, key=len)`

Comment: Yes, you are right Patrick. But I am not sure how to define different function and call one function into another function.

Comment: I think I found it.  I can just do not return the lst1.  like def best(lst1,lst2):
    return max(lst2,key=len)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
def len_score(name):
    lst = [len(x) for x in name]
    return lst

def best(func, lst):
    func_lst = func(lst) # call the passed in function ON lst
    return lst[func_lst.index(max(func_lst))]

names = ["Ben", "April", "Zaber", "Alexis", "McJagger", "J.J.", "Madonna"]

print(best(len_score, names) == 'McJagger')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

```
def len_score(name):
    lst=[len(x) for x in name]
    return lst

def best(lst1,lst2):
    final=zip(lst1,lst2)
    return max(final)

names = ["Ben", "April", "Zaber", "Alexis", "McJagger", "J.J.", "Madonna"]

print(best(len_score(names), names)[1])
print(best(len_score(names), names)[1] == 'McJagger')
```

Working code: https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user302_Lx3nAppYJe_0.py